# Will Bcc work when emailing mms numbers?

Tags: gmail, mms

I want to send the same message to multiple people with an "mms email"(number@mms.att.net, number@vzwpix.com, number@pm.sprint.com, etc). If I use Bcc, will it still put all these people in a group chat or will it send them individual texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will send through as individual texts.